Car Jerks when AC compressor turns on
I have a manual patrol car with a very small engine (800cc). It was a used car when I bought it and this issue was there from the day 1 I bought. I thought the issue maybe due to the small engine but I happened to drive another same model car and it did not had such an issue.
So imagine the following scenario.

I am driving downhill on 3rd gear around 35 - 40kmph. And I am not
using the accelerator. And suddenly the AC compressor turns on.

As soon as the AC compressor turns on, car jerks ( jump forward ) and stabilize again. After the first jerk it will do another one or two jerks. So currently what I do is when the first jump happens I immediately press the clutch and then I don't get the rest of the jerks and slowly lift the clutch.
It only happens when I dont use the accelerator and driving on engine break. If I do use the enough accelerator there's no jerks.
Even though this car is really old, the AC is really good. I feel like its too good comparing the quality of this car. Seller also did some AC repairs before they sold the car.
Also I recently had to do EFI cleanup. This problem seems to got more intense after the cleanup as well.
Based on my recent research I suspect it might be, a AC module issue or Alternator issue or IAC valve issue but I am not sure.
But I am not expert in this domain and would really appreciate if you can help me to figure out which might be the problem.
Update
Model: Suzuki Alto 2010
Millage: 125000KMs

If you run the engine in neutral and turn on the AC what happens? Does the engine seem to surge or miss?

@GdD No issue on neutral. This also happens when I drive on a gear and suddenly release the accelerator ( without pressing clutch ) but only if the AC compressor is running.

Does your ac use r12 or r134a? Ac load on engines are more pronounced in small engines. Comparing your ac with another car that doesn't exhibit lurching seems to point to the ac system. Overcharging a system can create more engine drag as one explanation.

Thank you for the comment @FDryer .There's a sticker says "R134a use only" on the car but I am not sure which one is currently used, because before I purchase it, they did a full AC repair and not sure if they used the correct one. Is there a way to check ?

Google search; r134a in Suzukis from 2009. I do not know if repairs used r134a in the correct amount, over filled or a substitute r134a was installed. There might be a possibility of overfilling with increased operating pressures that can rob power from the engine. Service manuals have info on operating pressures related to ambient temperature and humidity when using ac pressure gauges. Another way to determine refrigerant amount is removing it, evacuating the system, then refilling with the specified amount from labeling in the engine bay, owner's manual or service manuals.
